# How can I intercept some HTTP request fallback to custom file?

Tags: electron

I use

```
win.loadURL('http://example.com/index.html')
```

to load a page, and I want to intercept this request
fallback to custom file like:

```
protocol.interceptStringProtocol('http', (request, callback) => {
   ...
   callback({
     data: fs.readFileSync(path.normalize(${__dirname}/index.html), 'utf-8')
   })
})
```

this will intercept all HTTP requests from this page. How can I do only intercept some HTTP requests?